# Perform standard deserialization when a child class is specified. JSON Inheritance

Tags: java, json, jackson

I ran into a problem with JSON Inheritance. I have an interface and several implementations. I wanted to implement a mechanism in which Jackson would determine which class to deserialize JSON to, based on the field that I pass in this JSON file. For these purposes, I used @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes.

However, having implemented this mechanism, I found that now when trying to deserialize any child class, the ObjectMapper requires specifying the field "type" in JSON file, even when a child class is specified.

It turns out that using Json inheritance breaks the usual mechanism of deserialization of JSON files, because now I can't deserialize proper JSON in the usual way. And I wouldn't want that at all.

I would like the field "type" to be required only when I try to deserialize to the interface.

Maybe you know any additional configuration that can help me solve this problem?

Hope this example will be useful.

```
@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")})
public abstract class Animal {
    private String sound;

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Animal animal = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{ \"type\": \"cat\", \"sound\": \"mew\" }", Animal.class); // everything ok
        System.out.println(animal.getSound());

        Cat cat = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{ \"sound\": \"mew\" }", Cat.class); // exception
        System.out.println(cat.getSound()); 
    }
}
```

I found that you can set objectMapper.configure(USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_SIMPLE, true). With this setting, ObjectMapper tries to use a standard deserializer if the type field is not specified. But I would like to know if there is a solution that does not require additional configuration of ObjectMapper?

Comment: In your case the type is always mandatory in the Json, otherwise a serialize - deserialize will not work even with the concrete sub classes. If you want to avoid the type prop, you could assign it to the interface or abstract class. Otherwise you could use a custom Deserializer. If you need help on that, let me know